# R: makePSOCKcluster hyperthreads 50% of CPU cores

Tags: r, parallel-processing, hyperthreading

I try to run an R script on a single Linux machine with two CPUs containing 8 physical cores each.
The R code automatically identifies the number of cores via `detectCores()`, reduces this number by one and implements it into the `makePSOCKcluster` command. According to performance parameters, R only utilizes one of CPUs and hyperthreads the included cores. No workload is distributed to the second CPU.

In case I specify `detectCores(logical = FALSE)`, the observed burden on the first CPU becomes smaller but the second one is still inactive.

How do I fix this? Since the entire infrastructure is located in a single machine, `Rmpi` should not be necessary in this case.

FYI: the R script consists of `foreach` loops that rely on the `doSNOW` package.

Comment: Would you mind to also post an output from the actual hardware NUMA-discovery process, as reported from **`lstopo`**?

Answer (score 1):

try using [*makeCluster()*](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/parallel/html/makeCluster.html) and define the cluster type and length with a task\worker list.
it works for me and runs each task on a different core\process.
consider (if possible) redefining each task separately and not just using *foreach*.

here is an example of what i'm using,
the result of *out* would be a list of all results from each core by order from the list.

```
tasks = list(task1,taks2, ...)
cl = makeCluster(length(Tasks), type = "PSOCK")
clusterEvalQ(cl,c(library(dplyr),library(httr)))
clusterExport(cl, list("varname1", "varname2"),envir=environment())
out <- clusterApply(
      cl,
      Tasks,
      function(f) f()
    )
```

Comment: I use nested `foreach` loops with more than 8000 interations in total of which each generates a raster file. Thus, there are a lot more tasks than workers. Each raster file relies on different shapefiles and bigger raster files. That is easy to model in a loop but appears not feasible under the above stated design.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is not to rely on `snow` in my case. Instead I launch the R script with `mpirun` and let this command manage the parallel environment from outside R. `doSNOW` needs to be replaced with `doMPI` accordingly.

With this setup both CPUs are adequately utilized.